# Firefox counterpart to Google Chrome - Developer Tools (timeline)

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-developer-tools

OS:WinXP

Is there any plugin for FF3 that can do the same like Chrome Developer Tools - timeline - showing loading time as a chart? Due to the compatibility issue, I need to debug under FF3 to see full functionalities. Please advise, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/)

Answer (score 2):

Firefox's built-in DevTools do now have a [Network Monitor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor) to view requests that the page is making over time.

Also, related to the "timeline" concept, a performance tool to show events, layout, reflow, etc. over time is under development.