# Which is the best available tool for measuring browser reflows in FireFox?

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox, pagespeed

I have looked into [this article by Nicole Sullivan](http://www.stubbornella.org/content/2009/03/27/reflows-repaints-css-performance-making-your-javascript-slow/) and it mentions about quite a few tools that can help in measuring browser reflows :

- Lindsey Simon at Google wrote a [bookmarklet](http://ua-profiler.appspot.com/reflows/) that tests reflow times on any browser. Fantastic. (Note: all that shaking is normal!)
- John Resig wrote a [bookmarklet](http://ejohn.org/blog/browser-paint-events/) to visualize paint events.
- Kyle Scholz created this [tool](http://www.kylescholz.com/blog/2008/11/digging_into_paint_events_in_f_1.html) to visualize paint events before onload.
- Alex at Yoono has created the [XUL profiler](http://www.kylescholz.com/blog/2008/11/digging_into_paint_events_in_f_1.html).

I tried to use the first tool but it did not lead me anywhere .Then tried the second tool but I couldn't find any info from that.Then I installed the third tool as an add on to FF but that doesn't give me anything in screen shot tab.  The fourth one gives me a 404 error .

So my question to all the gurus here in SO is which is the best available tool to measure browser reflows ? I am hoping that some new tools are out there since that article was published.

Comment: this have probably been answered here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7006152/how-do-we-investigate-how-many-times-a-browser-is-doing-reflows

Comment: @Arcadien I have already tried the point 2 in the given in the answer and that doesn't work for me .It is actually the third point in my question .

Comment: What do you mean by measure? Do you want to know the number of reflows? If yes, use the global [`mozPaintCount`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.mozPaintCount) variable.

Comment: @RobW I want to measure the number of reflows and how much time each one is taking .

Comment: @Subhra Number of reflows -> [`window.mozPaintCount`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.mozPaintCount). Measure time -> [`mozAfterPaint`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko-Specific_DOM_Events#MozAfterPaint) event.

Comment: @RobW the wiki on MDN says this "MozAfterPaint is a Gecko-only event, and for compatibility (and performance) reasons should not be used outside chrome code, such as extensions."

Answer (score 0):

The Chrome Developer Tools `CTRL+SHFT+I` have something like that I guess... Click the timeline tab and click the record button in the footer, see what happens to your page!

On the right all records are shown and when you hover over a record it highlights the element on your page.

Comment: I specially need it for firefox . I have edited the question.

Comment: Oh then this question might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4802836/firefox-counterpart-to-google-chrome-developer-tools-timeline ;)